# GlassFish deployment exception "jersey restful with entities"

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, glassfish-3

The following exception was thrown by glassfish server 3.1.2 with Netbeans IDE. I'm trying to build a restful service using jersey and entities from database(using hibernate). 
where is the problem netbeans does not deploy the application.

```
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void service.ClientXTicketAccordFacadeREST.remove(beans.ClientXTicketAccordPK) at parameter at index 0
      SEVERE: Method, public void service.ClientXTicketAccordFacadeREST.remove(beans.ClientXTicketAccordPK), annotated with DELETE of resource, class service.ClientXTicketAccordFacadeREST, is not recognized as valid resource method.
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public beans.ClientXTicketAccord service.ClientXTicketAccordFacadeREST.find(beans.ClientXTicketAccordPK) at parameter at index 0
      SEVERE: Method, public beans.ClientXTicketAccord service.ClientXTicketAccordFacadeREST.find(beans.ClientXTicketAccordPK), annotated with GET of resource, class service.ClientXTicketAccordFacadeREST, is not recognized as valid resource method.
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void service.DomiciliationXEtatDossierFacadeREST.remove(beans.DomiciliationXEtatDossierPK) at parameter at index 0
      SEVERE: Method, public void service.DomiciliationXEtatDossierFacadeREST.remove(beans.DomiciliationXEtatDossierPK), annotated with DELETE of resource, class service.DomiciliationXEtatDossierFacadeREST, is not recognized as valid resource method.
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public beans.DomiciliationXEtatDossier service.DomiciliationXEtatDossierFacadeREST.find(beans.DomiciliationXEtatDossierPK) at parameter at index 0
      SEVERE: Method, public beans.DomiciliationXEtatDossier service.DomiciliationXEtatDossierFacadeREST.find(beans.DomiciliationXEtatDossierPK), annotated with GET of resource, class service.DomiciliationXEtatDossierFacadeREST, is not recognized as valid resource method.
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void service.DomiciliationXStatutDomiciliationFacadeREST.remove(beans.DomiciliationXStatutDomiciliationPK) at parameter at index 0
      SEVERE: Method, public void service.DomiciliationXStatutDomiciliationFacadeREST.remove(beans.DomiciliationXStatutDomiciliationPK), annotated with DELETE of resource, class service.DomiciliationXStatutDomiciliationFacadeREST, is not recognized as valid resource method.
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public beans.DomiciliationXStatutDomiciliation service.DomiciliationXStatutDomiciliationFacadeREST.find(beans.DomiciliationXStatutDomiciliationPK) at parameter at index 0
      SEVERE: Method, public beans.DomiciliationXStatutDomiciliation service.DomiciliationXStatutDomiciliationFacadeREST.find(beans.DomiciliationXStatutDomiciliationPK), annotated with GET of resource, class service.DomiciliationXStatutDomiciliationFacadeREST, is not recognized as valid resource method.
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void service.UserXAgenceFacadeREST.remove(beans.UserXAgencePK) at parameter at index 0
      SEVERE: Method, public void service.UserXAgenceFacadeREST.remove(beans.UserXAgencePK), annotated with DELETE of resource, class service.UserXAgenceFacadeREST, is not recognized as valid resource method.
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public beans.UserXAgence service.UserXAgenceFacadeREST.find(beans.UserXAgencePK) at parameter at index 0
      SEVERE: Method, public beans.UserXAgence service.UserXAgenceFacadeREST.find(beans.UserXAgencePK), annotated with GET of resource, class service.UserXAgenceFacadeREST, is not recognized as valid resource method.
    SEVERE: WebModule[/testservice]StandardWrapper.Throwable
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1453)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1250)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5093)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5380)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

    SEVERE: WebModule[/testservice]PWC1396: Servlet /testservice threw load() exception
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1453)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1250)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5093)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5380)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

    SEVERE: PWC1306: Startup of context /testservice failed due to previous errors
    SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5380)
        ... 39 more
    Caused by: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1453)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1250)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5093)
        ... 40 more

    WARNING: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

    SEVERE: Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
    java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:138)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

    SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
    INFO: file:/C:/testservice/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/_testservicePU logout successful
    SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
```

And the web.xml is :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>Multiple packages, separated by semicolon(;), can be specified in param-value</description>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webresources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
     <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
     </session-config>
    </web-app>
```

Comment: i know it is a big stacktrace but what can i do ???????

Comment: I took care of formatting for you, but what is your actual question? Can you edit your post and add it?

Comment: Post the source of your ClientXTicketAccordFacadeREST class

Comment: it works now ,because i deleted all the the relation classes like vlientxticketaccord